# Why am I unable to sign my app on certain machines?

Tags: code-signing-certificate, mage

I have a ClickOnce application that I'm signing with mage

```
mage -Sign "Release\publish\MyClickOnceApp.application" -CertFile "signingcert.pfx" -Password MyPassword
```

This works on my development machine.  However, on every other machine I'm getting:

```
Unable to open certificate "signingcert.pfx":
Invalid provider type specified.
```

On my local machine when I try to open my signed app, I see my company name.  However if I take that signed app and put on another machine I get "unknown publisher".  It looks like my other machines are missing something, but I can't figure out what.